# Cup Product Structure on $H^*(M_g)$ from cup product on $S^1\times S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Hatcher 3.2.1 asks:

Assuming as known the cup product structure on the torus $S^1\times S^1$, compute the cup product structure in $H^∗(M_g)$ for $M_g$ the closed orientable surface of genus $g$ by using the quotient map from $M_g$ to a wedge sum of $g$ tori.

I know to use the induced map on cohomologies here, but I was wondering if anyone could help me understand the first part of this proof that should make things go much faster:

Since $M_g$ is connected, we know that $H^0(M_g)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and that the generator 1 of this group is the identity in the cup product structure. Also, we know that $H_2(M_g)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, so $H^2(M_g)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ by the universal
coefficient theorem for cohomology. Since $H^n(M_g) = 0$ for $n > 2$, we know that $\theta \in H^2(M_g), \theta \smile 1 = \theta$,
while its cup product with an element in any other dimension must be $0$. So it remains to compute the cup product of elements in $H^1(M_g)\cong \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$.

So, I don't really see how the universal coefficient theorem is being used here, and the argument that $H^n(M_g) = 0$ for $n > 2$ $\implies \theta\smile 1 = \theta$ is not clear either. How does this give us the cup product structure for every $n>2$?

Answer (score 1):

The cup product makes $H^*(M_g)$ into a ring -- in particular, we have $\alpha \smile 1 = \alpha = 1 \smile \alpha$ for *all* $\alpha$, always. $1$ is just the symbol we use for the multiplicative unit of a ring.

It is a little misleading to say "the generator $1$ of this group is the identity in the cup product structure". $\mathbb{Z}$ does not have a unique generator as a group; $1$ and $-1$ both generate $\mathbb{Z}$! However, $H^0(M_g)$ is always a subring of $H^*(M_g)$, and $\mathbb{Z}$ has a unique identity as a ring. This ring identity is also necessarily a generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group.

So really, the proof should start with something like

> Since $M_g$ is connected, we know that $H^0(M_g) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Then this group has a generator $1$ which is the identity in the cup product structure.

---

If $\beta$ is an element of $H^k(M_g)$ for some $k > 0$, we have that $\theta \smile \beta \in H^{k+2}(M_g)$. Since $k$ is positive, $H^{k+2}(M_g) = 0$! So, $\theta \smile \beta = 0$ for all elements $\beta$ in positive degree.